# Borrar cadena de texto hasta una palabra específica en PHP

Tags: php, str-replace, string

tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo una ruta con "realpath" y necesito mostrar solo una porción de esa ruta. Por ejemplo la ruta es:

**C:/Xampp/htdocs/proyecto01/imagenes/imagen.jpg**

Necesito mostrar toda la ruta que venga después de "**proyecto01**": algo así en este caso:

"**imagenes/imagen.jpg**".

El problema es que la ruta es dinámica y podría ser por ejemplo:

**D:/xampp/htdocs/proyecto03/imagenes/grandes/imagen.jpg**.

En este último caso necesitaría mostrar: "**imagenes/grandes/imagen.jpg**"

Por lo que no me sirve hacer un "**str_replace**". El único dato que tengo es que necesito mostrar la ruta a partir de la carpeta "**imagenes**" que sería la única que se repite siempre.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo puedo resolverlo?

Muchas gracias!!

saludos.

Comment: mira esto http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/like-valor-php-738733/

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente encontré una solución con explode y la dejo acá por si a alguien le sirve:

```
<?php 
   $ruta = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value); //obtengo la ruta real
   $string = (string)$ruta; // convierto la ruta en string

   // reemplazo los caracteres para obtener una ruta relativa
   $reemplazar = srt_replace('\\', '/', $string); 

   //divido el string en dos para obtener los caracteres antes y después de "imagenes"

   $encontrar = explode("imagenes/", $reemplazar);

   // llamo el resultante "1" del explode que corresponde a todos los caracteres que
   //vienen después de "imagenes/" (0 sería todo lo anterior a imagenes)

   $rutaFinal = $encontrar[1];

   echo $rutaFinal;

?>
```

Saludos.

Héctor